# Brownian bridge to unknown via extremum

Tags: time-series, stochastic-processes, extreme-value, random-walk, brownian-motion

Suppose, I know what's the minimum $\min$ of a random walk $w_t$ in period $[0,\Delta t]$. I also know $w_0$ and $\sigma$. How to construct the Brownian bridge for the latter period?

I guess it's not even a bridge since I don't know $w_{\Delta t}$, so my bridge starts at known $w_0$ and goes down to $t=\Delta t$, while hitting the known minimum $\min$ on the way. In standard bridge you go from known $w_0$ to a known $w_{\Delta t}$

Comment: "CONSTRUCTIONS OF A BROWNIAN PATH WITH A
GIVEN MINIMUM" https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ecp/1456938427

Comment: I saw this paper, cant understand the damn thing in it, bloody mathematicians, I hate them

Comment: To clarify, do you just know the minimum value, and not the time at which it occurred?

Comment: @AlexR.yes, only the exact value, not the time.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone, thank you, I figured out what they're doing, it turned out simpler than I thought at first. I hate the way they present results.